# How can I load a page via javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

There is a list of stores, when users select a store from dropdown menu, they should go to the specific URL.

Here is the javascript and HTML code but this is not working! What is the problem?

```
<script>
 function pageReady() {

    document.getElementById('store-id').onchange = function() { 
           var URL = "44805?id=57" 
           document.location = URL;

};

    document.getElementById('store-id').onchange();
}
</script>
<script src="/mcs/s/asset/34065/utils.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/mcs/s/file/54985/dialogs.css" media="screen" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" 
 src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
```

Comment: Did You call the pageReady function somewhere in Your code ?

Comment: Assuming you call `pageReady` on body/window load [it's working just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/94N3m/) so please explain what exactly is wrong and give more details.

Comment: Maybe you could give us a jsfilddle example?

Answer (score 0):

Use a jQuery load on a div:

`$('#myDiv').load('http://www.someurl.com');`

But maybe you want to navigate to a url. If you use a button, you could do:

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
           var url = $('#store-id').val();
           document.location = url;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use

> $('#Div').load('http://www.google.com');

as a jquery function to load a page in your div.

Answer (score -1):

Imagine this select control (drop-down list):

```
<select id="store" name="store">
<option value="null"> --- </option>
   <option value="1"> Store #1 </option>
   <option value="2"> Store #2 </option>
   <option value="3"> Store #3 </option>
</select>
```

Now, you just need the code below in jQuery to navigate your user to the new page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#store').change(function(e) {
      var target = $('#store').val();
      if (target != 'null') window.location = 'something.php?id='+target;
   });
});
```

As the user change your dropdown list, he/she will be navigated to the new page with his/her choice from your control.